# Override an inner function of a prototype function in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype, overriding

I have a javascript Object like below:

```
var Loader = function() {}
Loader.prototype = {
    constructor: Loader,
    foo: function(a, b) {
        function bar() {
            return a + b;
        }
        return bar();
    }
};
```

I need to override the bar() function present inside foo .
The foo function can be overridden as:

```
Loader.prototype.foo = function() {}
```

I have tried the same for inner function but no luck.

```
Loader.prototype.foo.bar = function() {}//doesnt work
Loader.prototype.foo.protoype.bar = function() {}//doesnt work
```

I would be very happy if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot override the inner function because it's scope is restricted to the function foo.

Comment: I guess you will have to override (copy paste) the entire foo() function and only change the relevant parts. Yes, it can be bad if updates arrive for what you are overriding (a 3rd party lib, perhaps).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current declaration, the `bar()` function cannot be modified. It exists in the scope of `foo()` method and cannot be changed from outside.

---

An alternative solution for a dynamic override could be:

```
var Loader = function() {}
Loader.prototype = {
    constructor: Loader,
    foo: function(a, b, barFun) {
        if (typeof barFun !== 'function') {
           barFun = function() {
              return a + b;
           }
        }
        return barFun.call(this, a, b);
    }
};
```

When calling `foo()`, it's possible to use a custom function as the 3rd parameter.
Then you can use it:

```
var loader1 = new Loader();

loader1.foo(1, 2); // prints 1 + 2 = 3, default bar() function

loader1.foo(1, 2, function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}); // prints 1 - 2 = -1, custom bar() function
```

Check the [working demo](http://jsbin.com/dafipi/1/edit?js,console).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, looks like i will have to go with this approach.

Comment: But `bar` can effectively be replaced by just assigning a different function to `foo` that uses different code than what `bar` is doing and this can be done from the outside.

Comment: @jfriend00 which means if I have 60 different functions inside foo() i will have to override them all.

Comment: @jfriend00 This is a skeleton example. Before calling `bar()`, the `foo()` may contain a lot of logic. Simply overriding it will create duplications.

Comment: @Sandeep - You didn't show that level of complexity.  You showed something simple to which I commented on.  Yes, you would have to replace the entire implementation of `foo`.  `bar` is private to the scope of `foo` and cannot be accessed from outside.  That's the way it is coded.  This is why I hate oversimplified pseudo-code in questions.  It does not show the real problem in enough detail for the most useful answers.  Real code in questions will illustrate the real problem you are trying to solve and will always get you much more useful answers.

Comment: @jfriend00 I wanted to override buildImage() inside parse() in this : https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader2.js. It was much easier to ask with a simpler example.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,the inner bar function is not the method of the outter  foo function which is the method of  loader object.Hope that it will help you

Comment: No this doesn't help. bar() is function of foo() which is function of Loader.

Comment: I just meant that it's not the method of it.